# How to avoid overlaping of frame of UIView inside a Scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have 6 UIView inside a ScrollView and with a panGestureRecognizer object I move them inside the ScrollView. I would like to avoid each UIView when moving to overlap other.

Is there a specific function or property we use for the intersections of UIView objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
CGRectContainsPoint
CGRectContainsRect
```

To determine if the boundaries of a view or a point are overlapping.